# how to use SharedPreference among activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, preferenceactivity

I Am writing a code using SharedPreference to store username and password of a user but each time I entered  information the older one in xml file are override by newer one what I have to to to get all my data?

```
 SharedPreferences sp1=getSharedPreferences("myshared", 0);
 sp1.edit().putString("name", name.getText().toString()).commit();
 sp1.edit().putString("pass", pass.getText().toString()).commit();
 sp1.edit().putString("age",age.getText().toString()).commit();
 sp1.edit().putString("id",id.getText().toString()).commit();
```

Comment: Of course it's overwritten - you are overwriting it!  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Review this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133636/why-my-sharedpreference-create-another-file-name-data-preferences/16144802#16144802

Comment: Also, for performance, you should only call `edit()` and `commit()` once (create a `SharedPreferences.Editor` variable).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're overwriting your shared preferences between activities. SharedPreferences are persistent like a file on disk, so you shouldn't ever have an issue with the values not being set, hence why you *must* be overwriting it.

You can get your `SharedPreferences` by doing

```
SharedPreferences sp1=getSharedPreferences("myshared", 0);
String name = sp1.getString("name", "noname");
String pass = sp1.getString("pass", "nopass");
...
```

You can determine if the name/pass was set by checking if they equal the default value (`noname` and `nopass` in this case, though it could easily be `null`).

Comment: It sounds that you are  telling me that my xml file will be overwriting my data all the time?

Comment: No, your XML file is not overwriting your data, you are physically overwriting it somewhere in your code. For example, you may be performing `sp1.edit().putString("name", name.getText().toString()).commit();` in `onResume` in your activities which will initially overwrite them to their default values. An easy way to fix this will be to *check* if the name/pass has been set *before* you call `sp1.edit().putString[...]` and if it isn't the default value, then don't overwrite it.

Comment: Simon:  Am trying to have all my data in my xml file not to overwrite them just like a registration system.

Comment: Dororo: Thanks a lot I will tray this .